# cygwin > xterm > bash > less : MouseWheel scrolling not working

Tags: cygwin, scrolling, xterm, less, mouse-wheel

I am trying to get mousewheel scrolling to work in less, within an xterm in cygwin with XMing x-server and fvwm window manager !

I hope I make sense..
I have tried rxvt, urxvt, urxvt-X, aterm, mrxvt without luck !

The only place this works is mintty.. but I won't use a non-X window just to get mouse scrolling in less.

Also, mouse scrolling in vim is working correctly!

Actually, mouse scrolling "works" but it is captured by xterm and not within less (meaning I see the previous commands from the command ilne when I scroll back)

And, last, I have tried a possible solution found online but it didn't work either.
the one where you `echo -e '\e[?1000l'` to turn on mouse capturing.

Am I missing something here? or it just doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this works in mintty is that it translates mousewheel events to arrow up/down keypresses when an application activates the so-called alternate screen but not mouse reporting mode. I think Gnome Terminal and KDE Konsole do this as well, but apparently the ones you tried do not.

In the mouse reporting mode activated with `echo -e '\e[?1000l'`, special control sequences are sent for mouse events, which need to be supported in the application. The likes of `vim` and `emacs` do this, but `less` does not.

Comment: I see.. So bottom line, I can't do this without a patch for less :)

Comment: I just found out the cygwin-ports and I added gnome-terminal which supports this! thanks for the info :]

Answer (score 0):

As of release 543 ([Enhancement 272](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html)) this is now supported. To use it you need the `--mouse` option. To use it with man the `LESS` environment variable is useful.